# criteria->group not works in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to use criteria->group in yii query but it gives error like

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S21]
```

currently i use is:

```
$criteria->group = 'reg.user_first_name';
$criteria->order = 't.inout_time';
```

when i use only order by then it works proper like:

```
SELECT `t`.`attendant_id`, `t`.`user_id` FROM `attendance_master` `t`
LEFT JOIN registration_master reg on reg.ai_sync_id = t.user_id 
WHERE (((t.well_master_id=:ycp0) AND (t.status=:ycp1)) AND (t.user_type_id=:ycp2)) AND (t.inout_time LIKE :time) 
ORDER BY t.inout_time LIMIT 10. 
Bound with :ycp0='1429082167', :ycp1='in', :ycp2='2', :time='2015-05-06%'
```

but when i add group by condition then error occurs like:

```
1060 Duplicate column name 'ai_sync_id'. The SQL statement executed was: 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `attendance_master` `t` 
LEFT JOIN registration_master reg on reg.ai_sync_id = t.user_id 
WHERE (((t.well_master_id=:ycp0) AND (t.status=:ycp1)) AND (t.user_type_id=:ycp2)) AND (t.inout_time LIKE :time) 
GROUP BY reg.user_first_name) sq. 
Bound with :ycp0='1429082167', :ycp1='in', :ycp2='2', :time='2015-05-06%'
```

i know this is a small issue but i cant find as i am new in yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't group by `reg.user_first_name` when do `SELECT t.attendant_id, t.user_id FROM ...` group field must be in result set.

So try just:

```
SELECT `t`.`attendant_id`, `t`.`user_id`, reg.user_first_name  FROM
```

and if you do `GROUP BY` you should use any aggregate function (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX` ...)usually.

Comment: thanks a lot alex. your first solution is useful for me.

Comment: now i have 3 records with same name and i want to saw a record with highest date which is "t.inout_time" . but this query doesnt show result like this even i have puted $criteria->order = 't.inout_time DESC' . so any suggestion...

Comment: create another question, show current query, show data sample (sqlfiddle would  be perfect), show expected result